# Why does Mailgun requires much information for domain verification?

Tags: dns, mailgun

I switched to use Mailgun from Sendgrid for email sending, we have several domains which would like to send email via Mailgun, to verify a domain, it requires for lot of DNS configuration like TXT, CNAME, MX... while with Sendgrid, it just asks me for 3 CNAME.

I'm not sure why Mailgun requires to configure much DNS information like that, does it take any advantages over SendGrid with just CNAME, if not, I think they should investigate and apply the Sendgrid way.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the use of each type of record for such mail service, For sending an email all you need to do is verify that you own the domain from which you are sending the email, they way these companies verifies the domain is by checking the DNS entry for either a CNAME or TXT record. Ideally post this verification you should be able to send email from either of the service.

The requirement of adding the additional records in the DNS zone are for use cases like -

1. TXT records - DKIM and SPF records, Adding these records ensures that your emails doesn't go to spam as the other email service providers verify if its a valid email from a valid sender using DKIM and SPF records. So you need to add the DKIM and SPF records.
2. CNAME record - Now a days everyone wants to track the email activities done by the users on the email sent to them. Activities like email opens, link clicks etc. These can be done by the email service providers but the urls of the links are converted to the email providers domain urls for tracking. If we want to have our own domain name for all links in the email including the tracking links, thats where a CNAME record for a subdomain is mapped to email providers domain and than that subdomain is used for all links.
3. MX record - This is required in case you want to receive emails via the email provider of your choice. If you are already using some other email provider for receiving the emails on your domain, you don't need to set up this.